# Exporting OBJ missing map_Kd

Tags: texturing, uv, export

I am using Blender 2.76. I have a cube with a texture I would like to export as an OBJ. But each time I do so the path to the texture is not included in the MTL file, but the texture coords are included in the OBJ file. How can I fix this? I am pretty new to Blender so sorry if I gave not enough information.

Comment: MTL files that generate alongside OBJ files are pretty open ended and depend on the program that you intend to use with them.  What program are you trying to export to?

Comment: I am writing my own game engine, framework and library from the ground up in C#. Was busy writing a parser and was in need of an OBJ model file. When I tried to export one in Blender I noticed the texture was missing.

Comment: In a word: without the .blend file, we cannot help. We can try to guess what’s going wrong but this is wasting time mostly…

Answer (score 1):

In the export window verify the checkbox "Write materials" is checked. Also ensure you have all the textures as external files (not packed in the blend file itself).
Also ensure you have created the material. In Blender, it's possible to see a textured object in the viewport after unwrapping it, but without creating a material at all. If the material isn't created, you might see it in the viewport, but it won't be "real." =)