# Export to OBJ missing texture image name

Tags: texturing, uv, objects, export, image

This question is same as some other question [Exporting OBJ missing map_Kd](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51521/exporting-obj-missing-map-kd), but I have more detailed information to explain.

So, I have this .blend [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B--IonFKyfKCUjFQVWJ1LUowSE0/view?usp=sharing) which for each face I conducted smart uv unwrapping, and assigned some texture image.

When I try to save this scene into .obj file, the resulting mtl file does not contain the texture image names.

Can anyone try this and let me know what is wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You dont "assing textures to faces" only materials. OBJ is a geometry file format, and MTL is a basic material description format, non can save texture data. and no file format you use exports textures. Even material definitions are not properly exported by any format for that matter.

Comment: Duarte, mtl file supports texture image names using map_Kd keyword

Comment: As far as I know they are kept as external files at best. Either way as explained in the linked question I don't think they will do you any good at all. Exported materials are basic, and most likely useless for any final results